# apply regexp in one data frame based on the column in another data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have two data frames --- table A is the pattern table, and table B is the name table. I want to subset table B, where it matches the pattern in table a.

```
A <- data.frame(pattern = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"))
B <- data.frame(name = "aa1", "bb1", "abc", "def" ,"ddd")
```

I'm trying to do a for loop looks like:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(A)){
for (j in 1:nrow(B)){
DT <- data.frame(grep(A$pattern[i], B$name[j], ignore.case = T, value = T))
}}
```

And I want my resulting table `DT`to only contains `aa1`, `bb1`, and `ddd`

But it's super slow.  I just wondering if there's any more efficient way to do it? Many thans!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a double loop, the following uses only a `sapply` loop.

```
inx <- unlist(sapply(A$pattern, grep, B$name))
B[inx, , drop = FALSE]
#  name
#1  aa1
#2  bb1
#5  ddd
```

Answer (score 1):

it appears there's a slight error in your sample input data (missing `B$name` is not properly declared and need to include `stringsAsFactors = F` for both `data.frame` objects):

```
> A <- data.frame(pattern = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"), stringsAsFactors = F)
> B <- data.frame(name = c("aa1", "bb1", "abc", "def" ,"ddd"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**CODE**

```
# using sapply with grepl
> indices <- sapply(1:nrow(A), function(z) grepl(A$pattern[z], B$name[z]))
> indices
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

> B[indices, ]
[1] "aa1" "bb1" "ddd"
```