# apply regexp and update column across data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I have two data frames --- table A is the pattern table with reference names, and table B is the old name table. I want to subset table B, where it matches the pattern in table a, and when the cell matches, update the new column in B with the update column in A.

I have referenced [apply regexp in one data frame based on the column in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372881/apply-regexp-in-one-data-frame-based-on-the-column-in-another-data-frame/52373072#52373072), but it doesn't solve this case.

```
A <- data.frame(pattern = c("ab", "be|eb", "cc", "dd"), 
                ref = c("first", "second", "third", "forth"))
B <- data.frame(name = c("aa1", "bb1", "cab", "ccaa" "abed" ,"ddd", "ebba"))
B$new = ""
```

And I want my result table to be :

```
name       new
cab        first
abed       second
ccaa       third
ddd        forth
ebba       second
```

I was trying

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B)) {
  if (as.data.table(unlist(lapply(A$pattern, grepl, B$name))) == TRUE) {
    B$new[i] = A$update
  }
}
```

Any one knows any better solution? I prefer using apply family, but I have no idea how can I add column with it. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I edited my answer since I forgot to add the line to change B to a matrix first:

```
B <- as.matrix(B,ncol=1)
```

it should work properly now:

```
library(reshape2)
L <- apply(A, 1, function(x) B[grepl(x[1],B),])
names(L) <- A$ref
result <- melt(L)
colnames(result) <- c('Name','New')

    result
#  Name    New
#1  cab  first
#2 abed  first
#3 abed second
#4 ebba second
#5 ccaa  third
#6  ddd  forth
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` with sapply:

```
stack(setNames(sapply(A$pattern,grep,B$name,value=T),A$ref))

  values    ind
1    cab  first
2   abed  first
3   abed second
4   ebba second
5   ccaa  third
6    ddd  forth
```

you can also use `stack(setNames(Vectorize(grep)(A$pattern,B[1],value=T),A$ref))`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Your data
A <- data.frame(pattern = c("ab", "be|eb", "cc", "dd"), 
            ref = c("first", "second", "third", "fourth"), stringsAsFactors = F)
B <- data.frame(name = c("aa1", "bb1", "cab", "ccaa", "abed" ,"ddd", "ebba"), stringsAsFactors = F)

patternfind <- function(i){
  ifelse(grepl(A$pattern[[i]], B$name), A$ref[[i]], NA) 
} # grepl function for your apply

m = sapply(seq_along(A$pattern), patternfind) # apply function 

test <- cbind(B,m) #bind your pattern matrix to B
melt(test, id = c("name"), value.name = "new", na.rm = T) # melt data for output

   name variable    new
3   cab        1  first
5  abed        1  first
12 abed        2 second
14 ebba        2 second
18 ccaa        3  third
27  ddd        4  fourth
```

If you'd like to go the `data.table` route.

```
library(data.table)

DT.A <- as.data.table(A) # set as data tables
DT.B <- as.data.table(B)

ab <- DT.A[, DT.B[grep(pattern, name)], by=.(pattern, new = ref)] # use grep and by, leave out pattern if don't need to see what matched
ab[,c(3,2,1)] # reorder to your desired order
ab[,3:2] # subset to remove the pattern if you decide you don't want to display it

   name    new
1:  cab  first
2: abed  first
3: abed second
4: ebba second
5: ccaa  third
6:  ddd  fourth
```